# Looping through weeks of the year in Ruby (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, date, sinatra, datamapper

I'm creating a very simple timeshare application using Sinatra and Datamapper. Every user in the application will have n reservations and for the time being each reservation runs from Monday to Sunday and there can only be one reservation per week.

Now I will need a view with a textbox (and label) for each week of the year where the users will put their name (through autocompletion or something) and thereby creating a reservation for that week. And if the week is reserved the name will of course be filled in the textbox (and disabled)

It would be something like

```
weeks.each do
  find user that has reserved this week - and create a textbox
end
```

So my question I guess is as simple - how do I loop through all weeks of a year in Ruby?

Or would it be a better solution to just loop 52 times and make an array for each user with the numbers of reserved weeks in it?

Comment: 365/7.0 is not 52 so I think it is slightly more complicated than that.

Comment: Yeah that's a problem. I do not really know how to work with dates in Ruby (or in programming in general) so I can't figure out how to find the number of weeks in a given year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1..52).each do |week|
   # find user that has reserved this week - and create a textbox
end
```

Comment: I edited my question before I saw your answer :) So that is how I do it. But...how do I find the week number for the reserved dates - if I later want to be able to reserved from say only monday to thursday?

Comment: Store the week number as a field in the reservation instead of date ranges.

Comment: So is there a way in Ruby to calculate the week number according to the ISO-8601 standard?

Comment: I think you can use Date#cweek : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000659

Comment: Aah...thank you. That's what I was looking for. So I'll use that function to figure out what week January 31st is for any given year and loop either 52 or 53 times. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through this:

```
(Date.beginning_of_year.cweek...Date.today.end_of_year.cweek).each do |week|
  find user that has reserved this week - and create a textbox
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For others that might find this old question, like I did...

January 1 is sometimes week 53. December 31 is sometimes week 1.  If you want to loop through all the weeks of the year, you must first decide if you want the first days of january, even when it could be the previous year's week 53.

To get the highest week-number in a year, you can always check december 28 (since ISO-weeks state that week 1 is the week with the first thursday).

If you don't care about the first days of january (might be fri-sun), you might do something like:

```
require 'date' # Already included in sinatra though

(1..Date.parse("#{year}-12-28").cweek).each do |week|
  puts week
end
```