# Rails 3 week display

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How Can i display the remaining weeks of the year in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Date.today.cweek...Date.today.end_of_year.cweek)
```

**EDIT**

```
(Date.today.cweek...Date.today.end_of_year.cweek).each_slice(2) do |weeks|
  puts weeks.join("-")
end
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Would it be possible to group weeks together in pairs?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really specify a format here obviously, but something like this will show you the index of every week left in the year:

```
(Date.today.cweek..52).each { |w| puts w }
```

See [Looping through weeks of the year in Ruby (Sinatra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019045/looping-through-weeks-of-the-year-in-ruby-sinatra) for a similar question